# Как визуально изменить путь HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Есть путь до картинки:

```
http://site.com/goodsimg/00000010052/~1Картинка6.jpg
```

Надо сделать так, чтобы: `http:://site.com` не было видно при просмотре в консоли разработчика, то есть на выходе получить `/goodsimg/00000010052/~1Картинка6.jpg`.

Comment: о какой консоли речь?

Comment: @ArcherGodson Консоль разработчика в браузере

Comment: А при чем тут php, если речь о браузере?

Comment: @Visman ну может быть как то через сервер можно добавлять. То есть http:// добавлять

Comment: А путь до картинки у вас где прописан? В переменной? Или это srс реальной картинки на странице?

Comment: @Visman ну это будет src и он берется из БД

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коммент запихнуть не смог, если я правильно понял, т.к. это метка javascript.

В принципе, console показывает начальное значение href или src, а далее уже при наведении срабатывает механика браузера и подставляет домен, т.к. это абсолютная ссылка

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('img').getAttribute('src'))
```

```html
<img id="img" src="/goodsimg/00000010052/~1Картинка6.jpg" alt="">
```

В консоли будет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]